# What does the symbol "$|_{\epsilon=0}$" mean with a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What does the notation "$|_{\epsilon=0}$" at the bottom of the derivative mean?

[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers. To type math on this site, you need to use MathJaX. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (probably) means you evaluate that derivative in $\epsilon = 0$.

For example, if $f(x) = x^2$, then:
$$\frac{df}{dx}\Bigr|_{x=3} = 2x\Bigr|_{x=3} = 6$$

See also: [What is the name of the vertical bar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52651/159845)