# Origin of Evaluation Bar

Tags: definite-integrals, notation, math-history

Does anyone know the origin of the evaluation bar? (The vertical bar). Does anyone know when it was first used in Calculus? I tried to find info in Cajori's "History of Mathematical Notation" but couldn't find anything. I would like to know both who first used it at all and who first used it in definite integration.

Comment: Good luck; the vertical bar is probably the most overused symbol in all of mathematics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52651/what-is-the-name-of-the-vertical-bar-in-x21-vert-x-4-or-left-left?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For the origin of other calculus symbols see http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html