# What's the name of the vertical bar notation for evaluating a definite integral

Tags: calculus, notation

The only Calculus text I have handy (Spivak), simply calls it “the notation” when he writes:

$$
 F(x)\Big|_a^b = F(b) - F(a)
$$

and looking over online resources has turned up nothing. Is there a widely-used terminology for this vertical bar notation? I would like to put a useful index entry (or entries) in my LaTeX book for someone in a hurry looking to be able to typeset this.

Comment: ... Never thought about this. I would call it "Newton-Leibniz symbol".

Comment: I'd say an *evaluation bar*.

Comment: Similar to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52651/what-is-the-name-of-the-vertical-bar-in-x21-vert-x-4-or-left-left

Comment: Thanks to whoever closed this with a pointer to the duplicate. Apparently it's not possible to close your own question that way.